# How does the map() function in Processing work?

Tags: processing

I'm taking a class which uses Processing.

I having a problem understanding the map() function.

According to it's documentation(http://www.processing.org/reference/map_.html):

> Re-maps a number from one range to another.
>
> In the first example above, the number 25 is converted from a value in the range of 0 to 100 into a value that ranges from the left edge of the window (0) to the right edge(width).
>
> As shown in the second example, numbers outside of the range are not clamped to the minimum and maximum parameters values, because out-of-range values are often intentional and useful.

Is is similar to a random function but the range is set by the user? Also, i cant understand the explanation for the first example: it says the number is converted to a value of 0 to 100 into a value that ranges from edge to edge of the screen. im thinking why not just convert directly, the number 25 to the range of value pertaining to the screen?

Comment: May be unrelated: some references of the implementations in different frameworks/languages: gist.github.com/nkint/077b6deccdf61351f016dee5b83a2021

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `map()` function is a useful shortcut and you won't regret the time spent at understanding it.
This is its syntax:

**variable2 = map(variable1, min1, max1, min2, max2);**

The function establishes a proportion between **two ranges of values**:

min1 : min2 = max1 : max2

you can read it as: min1 **is to** min2 **as** max1 **is to** max2.
**variable1 *stores* a value between the first range** min1~max1.
 **variable2 *gets* a value between the second range** min2~max2.

This is the equation the function solves for the programmer:

**variable2 = min2+(max2-min2)*((variable1-min1)/(max1-min1))**

This is the Java code behind the Processing map() function:

```
static public final float map(float value, 
                              float istart, 
                              float istop, 
                              float ostart, 
                              float ostop) {
    return ostart + (ostop - ostart) * ((value - istart) / (istop - istart));
}
```

Comment: Imagine a potential use case of your program receiving normalized (ie 0.0 - 1.0) values from something, and then wanting to use that to change the colour of the background in Processing. You could go background(map(receivedValue, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 255.0));

Comment: @jesses.co.tt: I know this isn't the point of your comment, but in this case wouldn't it be much simpler to just do `background(receivedValue * 255.0)`?

Comment: @flarn2006 yes, map() is just a convenience function, and sometimes its a lot easier to do as you said... but i guess that map() is good to have around for more complicated cases...

Comment: The syntax `v' = map(v, x_1, x_2, y_1, y_2)` converts a value `v` in scale `[x_1, x_2]` to its corresponding value `v'` in scale `[y_1, y_2]`. Equivalently, `v'` is the unique value so that the three points `(x_1, y_1)`, `(v,v')` and `(x_2, y_2)` are co-linear.

Comment: Where in the source code is this (and other) function implemented?

Comment: Where exactly in the Processing repo did you find this? I was looking to port another couple of functions to Swift and can't find them in the sea of files that repo is.

Answer (score 2):

think of it this way: divide a range of 0 to 10 into 100 equal parts. (you will get 0.1 per part) now divide the range 0 to 100 into 100 equal parts (you will get 1 per part) so 0.1 in the range of 0 to 10 is equal to 1 in the range 0 to 100. if you want to find where 5 in the range of 0 to 10 belongs in the range of 0 to 100, divide 5 by the size of a 0 to 10 part and multiply that number by the size of a 0 to 100 part and you will have your answer! (50)

P.S. I know this isn't how it actually works, but I just thought I would give an example to clarify things.

Answer (score 1):

If you think it a bit more carefully,

Its nothing more than just calculating the percentage,

in percentage you have final range is 0-100 and initial range as 0 - max(example like you have maximum marks in all subjects is 500, then initial range is 0 - 500),

Now for the solution what you can do:

for step by step to understand

n - your number

(initialMin - initialMax) your initial range

(finalMin - finalMax) your final range

then,

**n**

**________________________    X   (finalMax - finalMin) = say N**

**(initialMax - initialMin)**

now N is exactly like percentage,, instead 0 to 100 as range, you have 0 to (finalMax-finalMin) as range

so for converting it into finalMin to finalMax range that map() function do in processing,

just do **N = N + finalMin**

Now you get the answer that is N

Hope you guys understand the solution>>>